# Getting error :" 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 2: invalid start byte" while writing data into csv file using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to write csv file in Python from MYSQL using the mysql.connector using the connection class but getting error :  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 2: invalid start byte"

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connection

session = connection.MySQLConnection(host = db_config.host , user = db_config.user , password = db_config.password , database = db_config.db )

curr = session.cursor()
curr.execute("Query")
records = curr.fetchall()
with open(extract_file, 'w' ,encoding ='latin1' ) as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=delimiter,quotechar = '"') ##, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in records:
        a.writerow(row)
```

I am getting error while writing BLOB columns values to the file
Any thoughts on this issue ?

while writing data

Comment: You have some junk data. Character 0x99 is [not defined in Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and can't be converted. Are you sure it's not something else like [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)?

Comment: Which line has the problem?